# Capture the weekly latest status through mySQL

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have a table called 'Hololive' stored in mySQL and I wish to write a query to extract the latest status of the vtubers in each week. The image can give you a couple of examples: basically the table has three columns 'Vtuber', 'Time', and 'Status' and I added a fourth column 'End of Week' to give the corresponding end of week date of 'Time' column for illustration purpose. The orange rows are the statuses that I want to capture for every vtuber in that week.

[Hololive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVaCq.png)

I know how to achieve this through Excel by ranking the table based on 'Time' column in descending order and further drop duplicates based on 'Vtuber' and 'End of Week' column; however, I wish to achieve this directly through code. Can someone offer me some insights or some sample sql codes to achieve this?

Thanks!